# How to access vscode internal APIs when creating extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a rather feature rich extension for vscode and using a lot of the APIs. However, I would also like to use APIs that are not in the `vscode.d.ts` file.

Is it possible to access the internal APIs? I'm happy to manually code definitions from vscode if required. What's the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported out of the box. You will have to do a custom build.

I've setup a Monaco build that exposes some internal APIs here : https://github.com/basarat/monaco . Since Monaco is built from VS. code you can use a similar automation workflow if you want to persue it in the long run  (As opposed to a quick hack)

Comment: He is building an extension for Vscode. Meaning runs on Vscode. How monaco can be any related for the extension building (for vscode) ???